# Inconsistent Batch Size Issue for Multi-Label Classification: Input [32, 3, 224, 224], Output [98, 129]

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface, image-classification

I'm using ResNet18 from Hugging Face to fine-tune a multi-label dataset. I want to be able to predict for an image it's 3 corresponding labels and for that I created 3 fully connected layers. First, I tried updating the classifier layer of ResNet18:

```
model2.classifier_artist = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=True), 
    torch.nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=num_classes_artist, bias=True)
).to(device)

model2.classifier_style = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=True), 
    torch.nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=num_classes_style, bias=True) 
).to(device)

model2.classifier_genre = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=True), 
    torch.nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=num_classes_genre, bias=True) 
).to(device)

num_classes_artist = 129
num_classes_style = 27
num_classes_genre = 11
```

But that didn't work. The model architecture didn't include the 3 classifiers that I added. Here is the summary from torchinfo:

```
ResNetForImageClassification (ResNetForImageClassification)                 [32, 3, 224, 224]    [32, 1000]
├─ResNetModel (resnet)                                                      [32, 3, 224, 224]    [32, 512, 1, 1]
│    └─ResNetEmbeddings (embedder)                                          [32, 3, 224, 224]    [32, 64, 56, 56]
│    │    └─ResNetConvLayer (embedder)                                      [32, 3, 224, 224]    [32, 64, 112, 112]
│    │    └─MaxPool2d (pooler)                                              [32, 64, 112, 112]   [32, 64, 56, 56]
│    └─ResNetEncoder (encoder)                                              [32, 64, 56, 56]     [32, 512, 7, 7]
│    │    └─ModuleList (stages)                                             --                   --
│    └─AdaptiveAvgPool2d (pooler)                                           [32, 512, 7, 7]      [32, 512, 1, 1]
├─Sequential (classifier)                                                   [32, 512, 1, 1]      [32, 1000]
│    └─Flatten (0)                                                          [32, 512, 1, 1]      [32, 512]
│    └─Linear (1)                                                           [32, 512]            [32, 1000]
```

After that I proceeded to implement it in PyTorch:

```
class WikiartModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_artists, num_genres, num_styles):
        super(WikiartModel, self).__init__()
        
        # Shared Convolutional Layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, padding =1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        
        # Artist classification branch
        self.fc_artist1 = nn.Linear(256 * 16 * 16, 512)
        self.fc_artist2 = nn.Linear(512, num_artists)
        
        
        # Genre classification branch
        self.fc_genre1 = nn.Linear(256 * 16 *  16, 512)
        self.fc_genre2 = nn.Linear(512, num_genres)


        # Style classification branch
        self.fc_style1 = nn.Linear(256 * 16 * 16, 512) 
        self.fc_style2 = nn.Linear(512, num_styles)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # Shared convolutional layers
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))   
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))       
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 256 * 16  * 16) 

        # Artist classification branch
        artists_out = F.relu(self.fc_artist1(x))
        artists_out = self.fc_artist2(artists_out)
       
        
        # Genre classification branch
        genre_out = F.relu(self.fc_genre1(x))
        genre_out = self.fc_genre2(genre_out) 
        
        
        # Style classification branch 
        style_out = F.relu(self.fc_style1(x))
        style_out = self.fc_style2(style_out)
        
        return artists_out, genre_out, style_out
    
# Set the number of classes for each task
num_artists = 129  # Including "Unknown Artist"
num_genres = 11    # Including "Unknown Genre"
num_styles = 27
```

And here is the torchinfo summary:

```
Layer (type (var_name))                  Input Shape          Output Shape
================================================================================
WikiartModel (WikiartModel)              [32, 3, 224, 224]    [98, 129]
├─Conv2d (conv1)                         [32, 3, 224, 224]    [32, 64, 224, 224]
├─MaxPool2d (pool)                       [32, 64, 224, 224]   [32, 64, 112, 112]
├─Conv2d (conv2)                         [32, 64, 112, 112]   [32, 128, 112, 112]
├─MaxPool2d (pool)                       [32, 128, 112, 112]  [32, 128, 56, 56]
├─Conv2d (conv3)                         [32, 128, 56, 56]    [32, 256, 56, 56]
├─MaxPool2d (pool)                       [32, 256, 56, 56]    [32, 256, 28, 28]
├─Linear (fc_artist1)                    [98, 65536]          [98, 512]
├─Linear (fc_artist2)                    [98, 512]            [98, 129]
├─Linear (fc_genre1)                     [98, 65536]          [98, 512]
├─Linear (fc_genre2)                     [98, 512]            [98, 11]
├─Linear (fc_style1)                     [98, 65536]          [98, 512]
├─Linear (fc_style2)                     [98, 512]            [98, 27]
```

The batch size of the input data `([32, 3, 224, 224])` and the batch size of the model's output predictions `([98, 129])` appear to be different. I've checked my data loading, model architecture, and training loop, but I can't seem to identify the root cause of this problem. This inconsistency is leading to an error when calculating the loss inside the training loop:

`loss_artist = criterion_artist(outputs_artist, labels_artist)` :

`ValueError: Expected input batch_size (98) to match target batch_size (32).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model architecture, you've defined 3 types of 2D convolutional layers (`self.conv1`, `self.conv2`, `self.conv3`) and one max-pooling layer (`self.pool`).

For the input tensor size `[32, 3, 224, 224]`, after passing through the specified layers:

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, padding =1)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
```

Based on your input tensor size - `[32, 3, 224, 224]`, after the image passing through

```
x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))   
x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))       
x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
```

, the size of `x` would become `[32, 256, 28, 28]`.

Now, you'd like to utilize the fully-connected network in the subsequent module. To do this, you should replace the line:

```
x = x.view(-1, 256 * 16  * 16)
```

with

```
x = x.view(x.size(0),-1)
```

This modification flattens the tensor to the shape `[32, 200704]` (256 * 28 * 28 = 200704). Consequently, you should adjust:

```
nn.Linear(256 * 16 * 16, 512)
```

to

```
nn.Linear(256 * 28 * 28, 512)
```

The revised `WikiartModel` class is as follows:

```
class WikiartModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_artists, num_genres, num_styles):
        super(WikiartModel, self).__init__()
        
        # Shared Convolutional Layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, padding =1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.size = 28
        # Artist classification branch
        self.fc_artist1 = nn.Linear(256 * self.size * self.size, 512)
        self.fc_artist2 = nn.Linear(512, num_artists)
        
        
        # Genre classification branch
        self.fc_genre1 = nn.Linear(256 * self.size *  self.size, 512)
        self.fc_genre2 = nn.Linear(512, num_genres)


        # Style classification branch
        self.fc_style1 = nn.Linear(256 * self.size * self.size, 512) 
        self.fc_style2 = nn.Linear(512, num_styles)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # Shared convolutional layers
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = x.view(x.size(0),-1) 
        # Artist classification branch
        artists_out = F.relu(self.fc_artist1(x))
        artists_out = self.fc_artist2(artists_out)
       
        
        # Genre classification branch
        genre_out = F.relu(self.fc_genre1(x))
        genre_out = self.fc_genre2(genre_out) 
        
        
        # Style classification branch 
        style_out = F.relu(self.fc_style1(x))
        style_out = self.fc_style2(style_out)
        
        return artists_out, genre_out, style_out
    
 # Set the number of classes for each task
 num_artists = 129  # Including "Unknown Artist"
 num_genres = 11    # Including "Unknown Genre"
 num_styles = 27
```